# Sliding contact form with push effect preserving slide down of page content with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide, contact-form

I was using the following to slide down a contact form using jQuery:

```
$("#panel").slideDown(1000);
```

What happens here is that the rest of the content of the page slides down to accommodate the contact form, which is what I want, but rather than 'pushing' the contact form onto the page, such that the bottom of the form shows first, it 'reveals' the form, so that the top shows first.  I would like the 'push' effect, and from searching here it seems that including jQuery UI and the following would do the trick.

```
$("#panel").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
```

Which it does.  However, now the rest of the content of the page doesn't slide down with the form, but rather jumps suddenly to the correct position to accommodate the form.

How can I achieve both effects, i.e. 'pushing' the form down, and sliding down the page content?

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">

<div id="contact-form">

*FORM*

</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#panel {
    display:none;
}

#contact-form {
    width: 840px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-420px;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible. For the effect you want to achieve, the only way is to cover the form by a opaque div, and on click of some button (or whatever event handler) slide that up, making it look as if the bottom of the form appears first, then all the way to the top. Since in this case the form is already in place, the remainder of the content can't slide up.

Comment: what's your CSS and HTML for the #panel?

Comment: The #panel DIV contains a #contact-form DIV which contains most of the the CSS for the layout for the form.  I have added the relevant HTML and CSS above.